# What is the best way to disable ad in Android?

Tags: android

I want to make a ad free version of my android app. What is the proper way to do this? Should I remove the following lines? Or is there any more simple way to do this?

```
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Answer (score -1):

There are few ways to do this:

1. You may add your device as test device `.addTestDevice("Device_ID")` providing your device ID.
2. You may comment out `mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);` line and then make a build for your device.